# Grails GORM with many-to-many properties

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes:

```
class A {
    int id
    static hasMany = [bs: B]
}

class B {
    int id
}
```

Can I use GORM to find all A instances that are related to a B instance with a given id?
I tried:

```
A.findAllByBs(B.get(bid))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Class: java.sql.SQLException
Message: No value specified for parameter 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Gorm documentation

**Querying Associations**

Associations can be queried by having a node that matches the property name. For example say the Account class had many Transaction objects:

```
class Account {
   …
   static hasMany = [transactions: Transaction]
   …
}
```

We can query this association by using the property name transaction as a builder node:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def now = new Date()
def results = c.list {
    transactions {
        between('date', now - 10, now)
    }
}
```

The above code will find all the Account instances that have performed transactions within the last 10 days. You can also nest such association queries within logical blocks:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def now = new Date()
def results = c.list {
    or {
        between('created', now - 10, now)
        transactions {
            between('date', now - 10, now)
        }
    }
}
```

**So this should work:**

```
def c = A.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    bs {
        // Conditions...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps or give any hint of how to follow.